# How to test google cloud endpoints on physical device instead of AVD?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am currently testing my google cloud endpoint via the AVD and calling the endpoint api methods like so:

```
if (myApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
                MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                        new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                        // options for running against local devappserver
                        // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                        // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                        .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                        .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                            @Override
                            public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                                abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                            }
                        });
                myApiService = builder.build();
            }

            try {
                return myApiService.publishReview(mUserId, mReview).execute().getTitle();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
```

I use `http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/` as the root url as it is the AVDs IP.
What modifications would need to be made in order to get this call to the endpoint method working on any physical device around the world?

Comment: Obviously: 1 deploy your project into google cloud or 2. use public IP on devappserver

Comment: So I have deployed to app engine would the root url be the url of the deployed instance. @Selvin

Answer (score 0):

As @Selvin said, deploy your project to Google Cloud.

You will want to use https://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/_ah/api/ as the root url.

See this for reference:
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/quickstart-frameworks-java#sending_a_request_to_the_sample_api